# Add mean of column A for each value of column B

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have the following pandas data frame (df):

```
       A    B   C 
0      2    1   4
1      3    4   5
2      3    1   1
3      1    4   0 
4      5    0   1
```

And you want to add a column containing the mean (or any other aggregate function) of column A for each distinct value of column B. You want to keep all columns. So the result would look like this (df_result):

```
       A    B   C   meanA_givenB
0      2    1   4        (2+3)/2
1      3    4   5        (3+1)/2
2      3    1   1        (2+3)/2
3      1    4   0        (3+1)/2
4      5    0   1          5  /1
```

The way I do that is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

meanA_givenB = df.groupby('B').A.mean()
df_result = pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame(meanA_givenB), 
                     how='left', left_on='A', right_index=True,
                     suffixes=['','_meanA_givenB'])
```

There must be a cleaner and more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
>>> df['avg(A)|B'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('mean')
>>> df
   A  B  C  avg(A)|B
0  2  1  4       2.5
1  3  4  5       2.0
2  3  1  1       2.5
3  1  4  0       2.0
4  5  0  1       5.0
```